# how the assignment is assigned for the if condition in below code

Tags: c, if-statement

How this code works .Here `i` variable gets assignment of `55` value .But why the `if` statement fails since i gets `55` not `0`, here else statement executed.How this interpretation happens .
As i expected `output` is `Test Skills 55`but its not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int i;
  i=0;
  if(i=55,0,10,0)
  printf("Test Skills %d",i);
  else
  printf("C Programing %d",i);

 }
```

Can any one explain how it behaves in above code?

Comment: Please avoid this kind of obscure and tricky syntax. If it wasn't you to write it, discard the source -- unless it was about obfuscated code altogether, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma expression

```
exp1, exp2
```

where `exp1` and `exp2` are any two expressions. This will evaluated in two steps:

1. `exp1` is evaluated and its value discarded.
2. `exp2` is evaluated and its value is the value of entire expression.

**NOTE:** *Evaluating `exp1` should always have a side effect; if it does not, then `exp1` serves no purpose*.

In your case

```
if(i=55,0,10,0)
```

`i=55` is evaluated first and its value discarded (but side effect to `i` has been done, i.e, `55` is assigned to `i`). `0` evaluated then and discarded. `10` evaluated then and discarded. After then right most `0` is evaluated and it will be the value of *entire expression* ((but not the value of sub-expressions)) in `if` condition and make the condition **false**.
But side effect to `i` has been done and that's why you are getting output as`55`.

Answer (score 0):

`,` operator executes from left to right. So the last value is `0` that makes the `if` false.

```
if(i=55,0,10,0) => if(i,0,10,0) => if(55,0,10,0) => if(0) => which returns false
                                     ^^^^-> Value of i
```

`i` is still 55 because `,`  has the lowest precedence .

`,` operator executes it's left expression and returns the result of right expression as a result of `,` operator.

Other thing to note here is assignment operator has higher precedence then `,`. That's why `i` got the value `55`.

Comment: Then how i=55 prints if statement execute from R->L

Comment: = has high precedence then ,

Comment: @vinayhunachyal your example doesn't match OPs ques. there is no parenthesis surrounding `55,0,10,0` in OPs code

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator is left to right.

You have values: `55,0,10,0` and the right-most value is `0` that means `false`.

Also assignment operator has higher priority then comma, so `i` is set to `55`.